# HttpWebResponse not providing correct value for headers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I was writing some test scripts to validate the headers for my .net webapi services.  When I look at the traffic through fiddler and invoke the service through my browser I see the correct header `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`.  However when the service is invoked with a WebRequest from my .NET test class and I read the response, Cache-Control is set to `private`.  Why would I be seeing different response header values based on the client that is calling the service?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know ASP.NET modifies the rendered HTML based on user-agent, so that's probably what's happening here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300549.aspx

So try using the IE9 user-agent string in your webrequest

Comment: That does not appear to have changed anything.